# MySQL performace across databases vs within the same database

Tags: mysql, database

In our software, we share information across installations.

Currently we use staging tables within the same database to facilitate this.  We use stored procedures to pull certain data from the live tables into the staging tables, and then dump them.  This dump then gets loaded into the staging tables of the target database, and stored procedures merge in the data.

This works fine, but for a few reasons*, I'm considering moving this from staging *tables* to a separate staging *database*.  I'm just concerned about whether or not this will have any performance implications.

Having very quickly tried this (just as a thought exercise) on a couple of differently configured systems, I've come up with differing results.  One (with not much data, and running MySQL 5.6) showed no real difference, possibly even slightly faster.  The other (with much more data, running MySQL 5.5) showed it to be about 1.5 times slower.

I'm well aware that there will likely be configuration options that may affect this, I'm no DBA, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

**TL;DR**
What performance implications might there be in inserting data into tables in a different database (on the same server), compared to within the same database.  Will it depend on MySQL version, or configuration settings?

* If you're interested in 'reasons', I can let you know in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that you cannot conduct tests the way you did.

Databases, and MySQL among them, rely on hardware. There are number of optimizations for MySQL variables available which can turn it from a snail to formula 1.

Consequently, you tested on separate systems, and each either runs on different hardware or contains different data. Technically, what MySQL does by default is use InnoDB storage engine. InnoDB storage engine, by default, stores all the data into a single file. So from some "down to the core" perspective, whether you use a table or a database - MySQL won't really care because it will store it into the one and the same file. From there on we get to the point whether the file is fragmented or not (if on mechanical disk) and to many other interesting details that can't be covered in a single answer.

That brings us to next issue - databases exist to store **structured** data.
Databases are not glorified text files. They exist so we can ask them to cross-examine data and give us meaningful results to questions.
That means we design databases and tables in ways that correspond to certain logic. If it makes sense to store those staging tables into database A, then store it. If it makes sense to do some other thing - do the other thing.

From performance point of view, it **hugely depends** on how your servers are configured, both from OS to MySQL variables, to which hardware (especially HDD) you have. Without knowing what's going on there down to the last detail - no one can tell you "Yes, it is faster", "No it is slower" or "It is the same". If they do - they're lying. We basically lack every possible information to tell you with certainty which approach is better.